# search query for booking a room

Tags: mysql, sql, search, woocommerce-bookings

So i have these tables

**Table Rooms**

room_id | room_name |room_capacity

**Table Booking**

booking_id | room_id | start_date | end_date | booking_status

Now, it is just a normal room booking except that it has booking status.

because my plan is that the user can book a resort on 3 different choices day/night/wholeday,

**Rules**

- if the booking_status = "day" meaning it's still **available for the night**,
- if booking_status = "night", **day is still available**,
- if booking status = "wholeday" then that day is already **not available**.

What I want is let's say the user wants to book a room, "day" on 2017-08-08, I want to show only the room that is available on that date and on "day"

here's what I've done so far. but it is not showing my desired result.

```
SELECT room_id FROM room Left join booking  ON room.room_id = booking.room_id
  WHERE booking.booking_status = "night" AND booking.start_date = "2017-08-08" 
  OR (booking.start_date <> = "2017-08-08" 
      OR booking.room_id <> any (SELECT booking.room_id 
                                 FROM booking 
                                 WHERE booking.start_date = "2017-08-08" 
                                 AND booking.booking_status = "wholeday"))
```

See, in my query i used `WHERE booking.booking_status = "night"` because the user wants to search for rooms available in "day" **(see rules)**. it's a bit confusing i know. So, can you guys help me write the query to get the available room depending on start_date, end_date, and time (day/night/wholeday)?

Comment: Get rid of wholeday as a parameter: Just make it a 2 part select (day & night). That simplifies things a bit. For the rest: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447087/sql-efficient-schedule-generation-algorithm/32447316#32447316 for a creative way of approaching a calendar problem (many other ways are possible, so the term "too broad" comes to mind)

Comment: Can't you just use a few more `AND` conditions? Like `AND booking.end_date`? Or are you asking how to actually calculate when the end date should be... because that's slightly complicated, and you'd benefit from a change in DB structure if that's the case.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I cant remove the "wholeday" because sometimes customer wants to book a room for the wholeday.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I am struggling with the booking_status part.

Comment: You can remove wholeday from the model: The frontend can say wholeday while the backend can work on day parts. It will really help simplifying :)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I dont know if I got you right, you mean if someone booked a wholeday I will push two booking in the database? day and night, is that right?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen you saved my life. its working noww...!!!!!! thank you thank you!